# Pass string from ASP Page (using vbscript) to C# DLL function as input parameter

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to achieve this but this is not working. I am sure i am missing something, please help me where i am wrong. I hope this is achievable. We should able to pass a string from ASP Page (using vbscript) to c# dll ( have this dll stored in gac and i have already registered it using regasm utility).

Below is my code:

```
Function GetObj()
Set Obj = Server.CreateObject("namespace.classname")

Set inputStr = Nothing
inputStr = "myString"

Set GetObj = Obj.dotnetMethod(inputStr)
SET Obj = NOTHING
End Function
```

The problem that i am facing is that when i passs inputStr to the obj.dotnetMethod, it is not recognising the string that i am passing from the asp page and it doesn't return to me any result which it should.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what the problem is? "It doesn't work" is a very bad description.

Comment: What do you mean, "it's not recognizing the string?" Do you even know if it's calling your method?

Comment: Yes i am sure it is calling the .net dll methods in asp page. The reason i say this that i have 2 methods. In first, i dont have to pass a string value, that method is work fine. But in this method, i have to pass a string from asp page, and this method is not working and i get the error message "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"...

Comment: It would really help if you at least included the C# signature of the method you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a unicode problem--.Net expects unicode strings. ASP, I believe, does not.

But if you aren't even sure the method is registered, well then you have to make sure that dll is COM visible. ASP is a world that doesn't know anything about managed code or .Net. You have to use COM. You know, old school regsvr32, or ASP won't find it.

Comment: I have already set ComVisible=true in my .Net DLL. Because of that, ASP is able to call the method using the .net dll object

Comment: Any help? Please let me knwo, i am stuck.

Comment: Nope, strings in ASP/VBScript are Unicode (that is the UTF-16 2 bytes per character code points) the same as .NET strings.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess at a couple of things the might be going wrong (your question really needs more detail)

```
Set GetObj = Obj.dotnetMethod(inputStr)
```

- `dotnetMethod` returns a `String`, `DateTime` or a primitive type such `Int32` in which case you should remove the `Set` keyword.
- `dotnetMethod` is return an object that isn't ComVisible itself.

BTW,

```
Set inputStr = Nothing
inputStr = "myString"
```

Why set inputStr to Nothing and then assign a string to it??